# How to change Regular Expression to give it a range

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var digitsOnly = /[1234567890]/g;
```

I have a regular expression like the above to restrict the user input to accept only integers. I want to give it a range. Any idea how to change it so that I can give a range lets say between 1 and 5?

It'll be great if anyone could help.

Comment: @PranayRana .. I really don't see how you can argue that.  That is not what range means.

Comment: @Daedalus - i given all the options as per my understanding in my answer that you can check below...

Comment: @PranayRana That doesn't address my post.

Comment: Explain what you mean, what are some valid input strings and what are some invalid input strings?

Comment: only valid inputs should be 1,2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: I agree with @JuanMendes . Please give examples of input which should match against some which shouldn't in the question. Add the beginning and end of acceptable range of inputs if it is just integers, as I want to accept all integers between 1 to 5 or all integers between 100 to 200 etc.

Comment: It should be pretty obvious.  "...accept only integers...between 1 and 5".  An integer is not a digit.  It is the whole thing.  *The entire set of valid inputs* would be {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}.  All of those, and nothing else, should match.

Comment: @CHao, it's not very obvious, you clearly misunderstood something, otherwise, Truth's answer wouldn't have a comment from era saying "ya this wont do"

Comment: @Juan: he's said the same thing i did, at least 3 times -- once in the question, once in the comment right after you asked about valid inputs (above), and once on Truth's answer, where he complained about "12" and "21" being matched.  It's pretty hard to misunderstand all that unless he's "asking" a different question than he's *asking*.

Answer (score 3):

```
/^[1-5]$/
```

I think someone should read a good regexp tutorial.

**Explanation**

- `^` Beginning of input: so that A1 won't match
- `$` End of input: so that 1A won't match
- `-` Range operator: The above regex is exactly the same as `/^[12345]$/`

Comment: @era If you like this answer, you should _accept it_ by clicking the green checkmark under the vote down button.

Comment: @Joey Of course, the point is to only allow 1-5 in the string. No other digits are allotted. We're talking digits here, not numbers.

Comment: i tried this ... but u can still enter 12, 21 but not 61... i want to limit it digits only between 1 and 5...so the valid inputs should be only 1,2,3,4,5
any idea?

Comment: @Truth: The user is inputting *integers*, not digits.  The "range" being referred to is the range of the *integer*.  Think about it...it'd be pretty useless in most cases to only allow '1' thru '5', but also allow as many of them as you want.

Comment: Corrected. Question was not clear, I thought he meant range of digits.

Comment: @Truth For a complete answer, you should explain what `$,^,-` mean

Comment: @Juan sadly I'm from mobile. Even typing this simple RegEx was hard for me. You are welcome to edit it yourself.  :-)

Comment: @era: Then your code is broken.  This does exactly what you asked, if used as intended.  If it doesn't work for you, then the problem lies elsewhere.  Show us the code and/or clarify your question.

Comment: @era Don't **ever ever ever** just say "this doesn't work" without explaining which part is not working. What strings fail your test using the regex above? Also, IM speak is shunned at SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[1-5]$/g
```

This should work for you, anything else really depends on what you want, but it is difficult to tell from a lack of information.

You can use ranges in your character class to reduce clutter, such as `a-z`, `A-Z`, or `A-z`.  This of course can also be used with digits.

If you want to repeat the given number zero or more times, use a `*`, if you want to repeat it one or more times, then a `+` is required.  Lastly, if you want to repeat it a set amount of times, enclose that number in curly brackets: {1} would repeat it once, {2} twice, and {1,3} one, or three times.

If you really need to learn more about regular expressions, I would recommend [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Would match "I have 1 broken regex".

Comment: @cHao You could alert me without being rude about it.

Comment: Rude?  Psh.  That was just an example.  You are not your answer.  Don't take it personally unless it *is* personal.

Comment: okay.. see none of these works... what i want is to restrict the user to enter a digit only between 1 and 5... meaning he can enter only 1,2,3,4,5???

Comment: @era: The corrected regex here should work.  Assuming you're saying like `var regex = /^[1-5]$/;`.  The `g` is unnecessary.

Comment: @era Going to try and replicate your problem.

Comment: @era Could you edit your answer above to show what code you currently have?